# Inner Items in UWP Grid not stretching XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

Having an issue with my items in this list view not spanning the width of the screen. Sorry if my code is sloppy. A bit new at this.  I do have similar pages with similar code.

Thanks in advance!

Not the full code - wasn't sure if you would need it.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" DataContext="{Binding ServicesCvs}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,80,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

                   <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>

                                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectServiceCommand, ElementName=serviceSelectionPage}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=ServiceIdTextBlock}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ServiceIdTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding ServiceId}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FF18417C" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ServiceType" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding ServiceTypeId}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FF414B59"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="AssetId_TextBlock" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding AssetId}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FF4D7CC1"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ProductItemId_TextBlock" Grid.Column="4" FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding ProductItemId}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FF414B59"/>

                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put this in your ListView, it will works in Designer too

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And as Mark Feldman said, remove that StackPanel and set button's HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch".

Comment: Awesome thanks! The XAML just made my life a little easier!

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1. Set your button's `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`. Your child controls may specify stretch but they will only stretch into whatever space the parent makes available to them.
2. Remove the horizontal StackPanel. A StackPanel overrides stretching and effectively says "reserve as much space as the child controls require for layout and no more".

Comment: Thanks Mark! Most appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

i'm not sure if this is the same problem you're having, but one of the things that drove me crazy about listview/gridview is that the **containers** wouldn't stretch. the templates would stretch, but only as far as the container, which by default, does NOT stretch.

the fix is to override the style for the ListViewItem/GridViewItem by adding something like this to your resources (either on the page or in the app.xaml resource dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

you won't see the results in the designer (!!!) but when you run it, it should stretch the contents of the item to fill the screen

i hope this is helpful!

Comment: Setting `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on `ListViewItem` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on parent `DataTemplate` control is sufficient.